# Wordpress Plugin for Secondary Categories?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I'm looking for a plugin that offers something similar to categories, but in a different container, to separate them from categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use [Custom Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) for that